# How can I save asp:HiddenField value across postback?

Tags: asp.net

How can I save asp:HiddenField value across postback?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This has nothing to do with ViewState.  A form control's value is maintained by doing a POST.  As long as the control is created early enough in the page lifecycle, the posted value will be set on the control.  If you refresh the page or click on a hyperlink that does a GET, then the value will be lost or revert to the designer-generated default.

Back to your question, if you have a designer-generated `HiddenField` (in the aspx file), it should automatically set the value on postback.  Either you're changing it somewhere else in your code or you are trying to access the value before it has been set (i.e. before `Page_Load()`).  If you have a code-generated `HiddenField`, it needs to have the same ID and be created before the Page sets the posted values, such as in `OnInit`.

I would recommend you read through and understand the following articles.  Otherwise, you will keep hitting walls because the Page lifecycle and ViewState are fundamental.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the links. I think the MSDN article did a far better job of explaining because it actually shows you the life cycle of the page and what happens in each step before trying to describe ViewState. The blog post seemed very scatterbrained to me.

Answer (score 14):

Placing and asp:hiddenfield inside an asp:UpdatePanel works.

Answer (score 3):

Set EnableViewState to True

Answer (score 3):

If you are dynamically adding it that will happen if its added too late in the page life cycle.  Add it in PreInit and you should be fine.  Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx for more info.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `asp:HiddenField` inside an `asp:UpdatePanel` works.

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, an
answer really needs a bit more detail than this.  Please
[edit] to provide example code to show what you mean.
Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.

Answer (score 2):

By default, it was built to do that.  There shouldn't be an issue there unless you've disabled viewstate for the control, a parent control, or the page.

Answer (score 0):

It happens due to the update panel please check your update panel. use a single update panel for the whole page.

Answer (score -1):

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
         <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnFld" Value="xyz" runat="server"/>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

If you change the hidden fields value using JQuery and after that the page get refreshed, the hidden fields value will be the new value.
now access the same using JQuery.

```
var currentTab = $('#hdnFld').val();
```