# dhtml popup window disappear when selected index changed event

Tags: c#, asp.net, popup, dhtml

I am using the DHTML window to show the div in a popup window. The div containing a dropdownlist with the property auto post pack is true.Now i selected the second list in the dropdownlist the total DHTML popup was disappear. Please help me to maintain the popup window during this type of action. sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

on the postback, the dynamically created html codes shold be lost. If you need the code, you can take the dynamic code  in to a hidden fiels and retain that code to the div on (ispostback== true) {} ON the page load event.

you can use this link for the ref.

[Hidden field and dhtml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3962512/1343516)

Answer (score 0):

As you are using popup so any postback will lost your popup. 
I mean your popup will be closed.
You need to implement jQuery with http-handler or web-service or page method to call you function.
Only then you will be able to stop pop up from closing.