# ASP.NET Hidden Field Not Posting

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have a basic web forms page that has two hidden fields, whose values are set inside a jQuery method after receiving results from Bing Maps. Basic structure is this:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hvLatitude" ClientIDMode="Static" />
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hvLongitude" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Here is a snip of the Javascript (cut out the Bing Maps call) that sets the hidden fields:

```
if (results.resourceSets[r].resources[re].geocodePoints[gp].usageTypes[u] == "Route") {
        console.log('found it!');
        var coords = results.resourceSets[r].resources[re].geocodePoints[gp].coordinates;
        console.log(coords);

        var lat = $("#hvLatitude");
        var lng = $("#hvLongitude");

        //make sure it only gets set once
        if (lat.val().length == 0 || lng.val().length == 0) {
            lat.val(coords[0]);
            lng.val(coords[1]);
            console.log('values set!');
        }
    }
```

When the code runs, my standard postback occurs and the hidden values aren't present - I've checked the fields themselves and looked inside `Request.Forms`, but they are empty strings. Tried `ClientIDMode="Static"` and `Auto` with no luck. The weirdest part of all is, if I do `$("#hvLatitude").val()` in the console (since Visual Studio is waiting on me to move a from a break point) and the value is there! It's the most confusing thing I've ever seen.

Any suggestions? No Javascript errors are present on the page, so I'm at a complete loss at this point.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961554/how-can-i-save-asphiddenfield-value-across-postback

Comment: Honestly doesn't make any sense.  Even if you have viewstate disabled on the page, it will still post the value back to the server (once anyway).  There almost has to be something clearing it after you've set it (prior to, or upon, postback).  Is that javascript code running multiple times?  Why the comment about "make sure it only gets set once" ?

Comment: Check if these two hidden fields are inside the page form, and check from network tab in developer panel if their value posted back, also if you change thier value in the postback function, does it change at client side?

Comment: Annnd fixed. Rookie mistake - the values were getting set inside a `$.ajax()` call that was running asynchronously, so the values weren't set before the page posted back. @kman - add your comment as an answer, because looking at the Network tab is what lead me to realize this. Thanks everyone for the quick help!

Comment: i think you meant @BasselEid - his comment mentioned the network tab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if these two hidden fields are inside the page form, and check from network tab in developer panel if their value posted back, also if you change their value in the postback function, does it change at client side?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var lat = $("#" + '<%= hvLatitude.ClientID %>');
var lng = $("#" + '<%= hvLongitude.ClientID %>');
 ...
```

Comment: I typically use ClientID like that, but since I wasn't having any luck I tried the `Static` option instead. So I had already been down that path unfortunately.